# Плохая точность у простой нейросети на Keras и Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

Я увлекаюсь программированием и в последнее время начал изучать тему нейросетей и ИИ. В итоге я с небольшой помощью ChatGPT сделал нейросеть которая отличает кошек от собак и у меня есть одна проблема. Какие бы значение я не менял, какие бы варианты я не пробовал, точность нейросети на тестовых данных всегда находится в районе 0.50
У меня есть четыре папки. В первой папке 100 .jpg фотографий котов, во второй 100 .jpg фотографий собак, в третьей папке 20 .jpg фотографий котов для теста и в четвёртой 20 .jpg фотографий собак для теста. Перед началом обучения нейросети, я обрабатываю все фотографии во всех папках следующим образом(не обращайте внимания что тут не обрабатываются тестовые фотографии, это я делаю отдельно):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

def normalize_images_in_folder_dogs(input_folder, output_folder, new_size):
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    image_files = os.listdir(input_folder)
    for image_file in image_files:
        if image_file.endswith('.jpg'):
            input_path = os.path.join(input_folder, image_file)
            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_file)
            
            image = Image.open(input_path)
            resized_image = image.resize(new_size)
            
            # Нормализация значений пикселей от 0 до 1
            normalized_image = np.array(resized_image) / 255.0
            
            # Сохранение нормализованного изображения
            np.save(output_path.replace('.jpg', ''), normalized_image)

# Путь к папке с исходными изображениями
input_folder_dogs = "E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\dogs"

# Путь к папке, куда будут сохранены нормализованные изображения
output_folder_dogs = "E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedDogs"

def normalize_images_in_folder_cats(input_folder, output_folder, new_size):
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    image_files = os.listdir(input_folder)
    for image_file in image_files:
        if image_file.endswith('.jpg'):
            input_path = os.path.join(input_folder, image_file)
            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_file)
            
            image = Image.open(input_path)
            resized_image = image.resize(new_size)
            
            # Нормализация значений пикселей от 0 до 1
            normalized_image = np.array(resized_image) / 255.0
            
            # Сохранение нормализованного изображения
            np.save(output_path.replace('.jpg', ''), normalized_image)

# Путь к папке с исходными изображениями
input_folder_cats = "E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\cats"

# Путь к папке, куда будут сохранены нормализованные изображения
output_folder_cats = "E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedCats"

# Размер, на который вы хотите изменить изображения
new_size = (224, 224)

normalize_images_in_folder_dogs(input_folder_dogs, output_folder_dogs, new_size)
normalize_images_in_folder_cats(input_folder_cats, output_folder_cats, new_size)
```

Код с обучением и тестом нейросети:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

# Загрузка данных кошек для обучения
cats_train_data = [np.load("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedCats\\" + filename) for filename in os.listdir("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedCats\\")]
cats_train_labels = np.zeros(len(cats_train_data))  # Метки для кошек

# Загрузка данных собак для обучения
dogs_train_data = [np.load("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedDogs\\" + filename) for filename in os.listdir("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedDogs\\")]
dogs_train_labels = np.ones(len(dogs_train_data))   # Метки для собак

# Объединение данных и меток для обучения
train_data = np.concatenate((cats_train_data, dogs_train_data), axis=0)
train_labels = np.concatenate((cats_train_labels, dogs_train_labels), axis=0)

# Загрузка данных кошек для теста
cats_test_data = [np.load("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finTestCats\\" + filename) for filename in os.listdir("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finTestCats\\")]
cats_test_labels = np.zeros(len(cats_test_data))  # Метки для кошек

# Загрузка данных собак для теста
dogs_test_data = [np.load("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finTestDogs\\" + filename) for filename in os.listdir("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finTestDogs\\")]
dogs_test_labels = np.ones(len(dogs_test_data))   # Метки для собак

# Объединение данных и меток для теста
test_data = np.concatenate((cats_test_data, dogs_test_data), axis=0)
test_labels = np.concatenate((cats_test_labels, dogs_test_labels), axis=0)

# Создание модели
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Добавление Dropout
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Компиляция модели
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Обучение модели
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

# Оценка модели на тестовых данных
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
print("Test accuracy:", test_acc)
```

И вот последняя эпоха обучения и тест:

```
Epoch 10/10

1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.1075 - accuracy: 0.9688
2/5 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.1291 - accuracy: 0.9531
3/5 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.1197 - accuracy: 0.9583
4/5 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.1356 - accuracy: 0.9531
5/5 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1195 - accuracy: 0.9625
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.1195 - accuracy: 0.9625 - val_loss: 1.1277 - val_accuracy: 0.4250

1/2 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1049 - accuracy: 0.4375
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 1.1531 - accuracy: 0.4286
Test accuracy: 0.4285714328289032
```

P.S.: Есть предположение, что нейронка плохо работает из-за предупреждений с Tensorflow которые выводятся перед началом обучения, вот они:

```
2024-01-07 00:54:24.324694: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\artyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\artyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py:873: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

2024-01-07 00:54:29.480529: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\artyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\pooling\max_pooling2d.py:161: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\artyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\optimizers\__init__.py:309: The name tf.train.Optimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer instead.

Epoch 1/10
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\artyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\tf_utils.py:492: The name tf.ragged.RaggedTensorValue is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ragged.RaggedTensorValue instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\artyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\base_layer_utils.py:384: The name tf.executing_eagerly_outside_functions is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.executing_eagerly_outside_functions instead.
```

Comment: точно в 50%, значит отвечает наугад. Вероятно данных слишком мало

Comment: @Danis, а что насчёт предупреждений от Tensorflow, они на что-то влияют?

Comment: Вряд ли они как-то влияют, но чтобы не думалось, то сделайте то, что пишется в WARNING. Замените то, что deprecated, но то, что он просит. Т.е. в первом "варнинге" в файле C:\Users\artyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py на строке 2976 замените tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy на tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy. Ну и остальные также.